# Why does the GAC folders structure is not documented?

Tags: .net, documentation, clr, assemblies, gac

Why does the GAC folders structure is not documented?

I am reading the **CLR via C#** book and in the book it is stated that:

> The reason that CSC.exe doesn’t look in the GAC for referenced assemblies is that you’d have to
>   know the path to the assembly file and the structure of the GAC is undocumented.

I can not understand what are the obstacles in creating the rules and documenting them for the GAC folders structure.

**UPDATE**
In the comments it was suggested that there is might be a technical issue, which does not allow to implement the rules for the folders structure. But I can prove that it is not the case by providing an example of a possible rule:

1 GAC can contain only strongly named assemblies.
2 By definition strongly named assembly is an assembly which has a name, a version number, a culture and a public key token (actually the public key, but we can use the token for simplicity, since the public key is too long).
1 2 -> 3 Each assembly can be uniquely identified by the name, version, culture and the public key token.
3 -> 4 If we use the following folders structure rule, then we will satisfy the initial objective of providing the desired folders structure rule: [name]/[version]/[culture]/[public key token]/[assembly itself]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: GAC requires specific version schema and strongly-typed names. Its structure can be specific for every machine, where .NET code is running

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, what is a definition of the version schema? Why .Net does not enforce rules for the structure of the GAC folders and allow the structure to be specific for every machine? Thank you.

Comment: because every machine can has own assemblies in GAC, or the same assembly with different versions and strong names. Please, have a look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, that does not answer my question. I will update it a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: A few things that make the actual structure less useful are,

* GAC structure has changed since .NET Framework 4.x, 
* Other implementations like Mono use different structures, 
* .NET Core does not even have GAC

You shouldn't really care about how GAC internally looks like, but merely use it as a way to share assemblies around.

Comment: @LexLi, hm. I did not account for the Mono. Thank you. Could you, please, post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET initial standard documents only define the functionalities of GAC, but not restrict its implementation. Therefore,

- .NET Framework 2.x/3.x has an initial implementation.
- .NET Framework 4.x uses a different implementation.
- Other implementations like Mono use their own structures.

Most importantly, .NET Core even has no GAC.

As a result, C# compiler cannot rely on GAC's implementation for its reference search algorithm.